# Calculate no of matches for __in or __contains lookup in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a recommendation engine and one of the sub-task is to rank `Venues` on the basis of `tags` matched in from a list of tags available.

Here are my models:

```
class Venue(TimeStampedUUIDModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    tags = ArrayField(
        models.PositiveIntegerField(
            verbose_name=_('tag'), choices=TAGS_CHOICES
        ), null=True, blank=True
    )
```

I could do a `__contains` lookup in the filter to fitler the venues where some of the tags from the list already exists. But my motive is to also somehow know how many tags are matched for each venue so that I can allocate some rank to them. For example, give a rank of 10 for each matched tag.

So, if a venue matches say 4 tags from the `tag_list`, it should have a rank of 4 * 10 = 40.

Since `tags` is an ArrayField which can only contain choices defined by positive numbers, `__contains` lookup works in the filter query, but how can I annotate the no of matches?

End result can be something like:

```
venue_queryset.filter(tags_contains=tag_list).annotate(no_of_tags_matched=...)
```

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved this using `Case` which maps to SQL cases using `When` condition.

Here `user_interested_in_tag_list` is the list of tags that are user interested in, and the logic was to rank each venue on the no. of tags that matched this list.

```
from django.db.models import (
    Case, ExpressionWrapper, IntegerField, Q, Value, When
)
from functools import reduce


def calculate_user_interest_rank(venue_queryset, user_interested_in_tag_list):
    if user_interested_in_tag_list:
        # Add rank of 10 for each matched tag in the venue
        user_interest_match_query = map(
            lambda x: Case(
                When(Q(tags__contains=[x, ]), then=Value(10)), default=Value(0)
            ), user_interested_in_tag_list
        )
        user_interested_tags_matches = reduce(
            lambda x, y: x + y, user_interest_match_query
        )
        venue_queryset = venue_queryset.annotate(
            user_interest_score=ExpressionWrapper(
                user_interested_tags_matches,
                output_field=IntegerField()
            )
        )
    else:
        venue_queryset = venue_queryset.annotate(
            user_interest_score=ExpressionWrapper(
                Value(0),
                output_field=IntegerField()
            )
        )
```

The `user_interest_match_query` will be a list of `When` clauses, including `Value` of `10` for each matched tag from `user_interest_match_query`, and `Value` of `0` otherwise.

The `user_interested_tags_matches` is then the summation of all the resultants of `When` clauses which gives the actual score of each venue as annotated in `user_interest_score`.

I hope this helps someone :) Let me know if you need any more details.